# Translating a kd-tree in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I'm using a kd-tree to perform quick nearest neighbor search queries. I'm using the following piece of code to generate the kd-tree and perform queries on it:

```
% 3 dimensional vertex data
x = [1 2 2 1 2 5 6 3 4;
     3 2 3 2 2 7 6 5 2;
     1 2 9 9 7 5 8 9 3]';

% create the kd-tree
kdtree = createns(x, 'NSMethod', 'kdtree');
% perform a nearest neighbor search
nearestNeighborIndex = knnsearch(kdtree, [1 1 1]);
```

This works well enough for when the data is static. However, every once in a while, I need to translate every vertex on the kd-tree. I know that changing the whole data means I need to re-generate the whole tree to perform a nearest neighbor search again. Having a couple of thousand vertices for each kd-tree, re-generating the whole tree from scratch seems to me like an overkill as it takes a significant amount of time. Is there a way to translate the kd-tree without re-generating it from scratch? I tried accessing and changing the X property (which holds the actual vertex data) of the kd-tree but it seems to be read-only, and it probably wouldn't have worked even if it wasn't since there is a lot more going on behind the curtains.

Comment: Are you translating every vertex by the same amount? If so, then it doesn't change the relative positions of the vertices and you should be able to use the kd-tree as is.

Comment: @beaker yes, every vertex is translated by the same amount. The relative positions don't change but the query vertex will also need to be translated since I can't translate the kd-tree. Thinking about it now, also translating the query vertex would be the most optimal solution for my case, so thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Yes, translate the query vertex coordinates using the inverse translation. Then, if necessary, apply the forward translation to the neighbor vertices.